# Laravel if database table empty

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a simple database query to put out some stuff from database like example:

```
$user->HeadHits = DB::table('csstats AS cs')
->where('cs.steamid', '=', $user->steam_id)
->select("cs.h_1")
->first()->h_1;
```

And blade:

```
@if ($user->HeadHits == 0)
0%
@else
<?php echo number_format($user->HeadHits / $user->AllHits * 100,2); ?>%
@endif
```

But i'm getting error if user steam_id not find in database:

**Trying to get property of non-object**

Any suggest? Thanks

Comment: Is `$user` an eloquent model? If so, do you also have a model set up for `csstats`?

Comment: $user is eloquent model. I think i getting this error becouse i'm using first. But i don't get it how to make work with "get();"

Comment: Do you have a model set up for `csstate`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because when you use `DB` (Query Builder) and `first` it will return `null` if the row can not be found.

You would need to add a check in to see if the value exists:

```
$cs = DB::table('csstats AS cs')
    ->where('cs.steamid', '=', $user->steam_id)
    ->select("cs.h_1")
    ->first();

$user->HeadHits = $cs ? $cs->h_1 : 0;
```

A shorter approach would be to use [value()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#retrieving-results):

```
$user->HeadHits = DB::table('csstats AS cs')
    ->where('cs.steamid', '=', $user->steam_id)
    ->value('h_1') ?: 0;
```

---

Lastly, just a FYI but you don't need to be explicit with adding the table alias before the column name since you're only querying one table. Also, you don't need to add `=` with `where()` as it will assume this is the operator that should be used. Ultimately, you can reduce your code to something like:

```
$user->HeadHits = DB::table('csstats')->where('steamid', $user->steam_id)->value('h_1') ?: 0;
```

Comment: Thank u, now i understanding! U  saved my life :)

Answer (score 0):

you can check that with isset()

like that

```
if(isset($user->HeadHits ) )
```